# Ubuntu 20 Very slow

Tags: 20.04

After updating from ubuntu 19 to ubuntu 20, My computer is much slower. If I watch some video it sort of lags and has fps drops. I think the entire computer has fps drops.
Its a 2011 MacBook pro.

```
$ free
        total   used     free shared buff/cache available
Mem:  5998812 2887984  181572 213920    2929256   2624648
Swap: 2097148  988648 1108500
```

Edit: I killed gnome shell as it was using 84% of my CPU and now everything runs great (after it restarted gnome shell)

Comment: Have you looked at `top` to see what's using all your resources? Have you looked at `free` to see if your lag is due to swapping? Maybe you picked up a cryto-miner. Maybe lots of possibilities.

Comment: @user535733 Gnome shell is using 84% of my CPU it says... I don't have the terminal open though.

Free:

Mem:        5998812     2887984      181572      213920     2929256     2624648
Swap:       2097148      988648     1108500

Thanks

Comment: "Gnome Shell" is not the terminal. It's the Desktop Environment - the GUI. Your `free`  result indicates that you are swapping, which tends to make systems quite sluggish -- so look for RAM hogs (like browser tabs) that are eating up all your RAM. Interestingly, 20.04 has many changes to *speed up* Gnome and to use less memory.

Comment: Oh okay. I just killed it and then it restarted itself and now it's using 6%. Also, I only have 1 tab open on firefox.

Comment: The browser was merely a common example, not a diagnosis. You must use `top` to figure out what's eating all your RAM...if swapping remains an issue.

Comment: Yes, gnome shell was using up the most resources on the computer.
Thanks for the help! Its all fast again now lol after i killed gnome shell

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.